# Отличие bat от sh

Tags: windows

добрый день!
Подскажите, в чем отличие *.bat* файлов от *.sh* в ОС Форточки 7

Comment: В том, что .sh вообще никакого отношения к windows и ее командным строкам не имеет?

Comment: @Fike ну это слишком смелое утверждение. Портов всяких юниксоидных шеллов по винды много. Вроде есть даже от MS

Comment: sh в "форточках" будут только если явно установить cygwin или аналоги.

Comment: @KoVadim native-портов тоже немало. msys, http://zsh-nt.sourceforge.net/  и т.д.

Comment: @alexlz а я что, не согласен с этим? я явно указал слово "аналоги".

Comment: @KoVadim хорошее слово "аналоги". Я-то думал, что это U/WIN и разные самописные posix слои поверх win32api (native-win порты к ним не относятся). Хорошее слово.

Comment: @alexlz  не материтесь! Я спросил банальную глупую вещь, а вы начинаете разговор о каких-то *самописные джигурда слои поверх трололо*

Comment: @voipp, а в чем отличие Си от Паскаля? Разные языки, хотя и одного сорта.

Также и bat от sh отличаются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Расширением ".bat" принято именовать пакетные файлы, что содержат набор команд для исполнения интерпретатором "cmd.exe".

Расширением ".sh" принято именовать файлы-скрипты оболочки Shell

Не смотря на то, что "*.bat" и "*.sh" намного чаще используются в ОС Windows и Linux соответственно, их можно успешно выполнять в обеих семействах ОС используя различные сторонние утилиты.

То есть, запустив на выполнение файл "*.bat" в OS Widnows Se7en мы тем самым инициируем запуск интерпретатора "cmd.exe" и пошаговое выполнение команд, заложенных в передаваемый пакетный файл.

Установив на Windows Se7en поддержку Bourne-скриптов, к примеру средствами Cygwin, можно отправлять на выполнение "*.sh" файлы, задействовав соответствующий интерпретатор.

Comment: Bourne тут не причем. Bourne Again Shell лишь одна из вариаций "родного" юниксового шелла. Я бы предпочел формулировку типа:

>Расширением ".sh" принято именовать файлы-скрипты оболочки Shell иже с ними

Comment: Bourne как бы предок всех и вся вариаций реализаций, если не ошибаюсь. В любом случае, целесообразнее будет использовать именно Ваше определение в ответе. Спасибо.

Comment: Bourne как бы шире родного шелла и стал популярным благодаря Linux'у и MacOS, во некоторых юниксах его по-моему даже и нет (могу ошибаться). Скажем, по дефолту в IBM AIX используется Korn Shell

Comment: @Barmaley мне глубоко на***** на IBM AIX и иже с ними

Comment: @voipp ваше мнение в общем то малоинтересно. Была дискуссия двух образованных мужей об истории вопроса :)